# Export the outlook 2016 address book

Tags: outlook

Is there a way to save a copy of the company address book to personal contacts in Outlook 2013 or 2016? I am using this method to get the address book onto a Windows phone user's handset!

Comment: Are you using Exchange Server as your email server?

Comment: What format would you like the contacts in?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to save the company address book to local contacts in Outlook, and I found a quick and dirty way: Open the address book, select all contacts, Right-click and add to contacts!

Comment: While that is indeed a solution, I think there might be a much better one, as joeqwerty implicates.